# Algorithm: get a O(n lg n/ lg k) algorithm rather than O(n lg n/k)

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a special high-performance computer. In this computer,
there is a dedicated bank of k optimization registers, where k > 2. Each of these registers can be used to store a key-value pair, and thus this bank of registers can store up to k key-value pairs. This bank of registers can support the following operations in O(1) time:

- Insert a key-value pair, (x, y), into this bank of registers; and
- Return a key-value pair, (x, y), which the smallest key, x, from the bank of registers. This returned pair is also removed from this register bank.

Design an algorithm that can take advantage of this bank of registers to sort n numbers in O(n lg n/ lg k) time.

---

This is the question. I did it by using divide & conquer idea. I think it is similar to mergesort. However, I can only get an an algorithm with O(n lg n/k). In most cases,O(n lg n/k) is slower than O(n lg n/ lg k), so I wonder how can I think about this question. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that `n lg n / k` is slower than `n lg n / lg k`? Since `lg k` is smaller than `k` for positive k, `1/lg k` is bigger than `1/k`.

Comment: @Nico there are brackets missing.  It should be O(n log n / log k) vs O(n log (n/k))

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense @Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, merging K sorted lists with a total of N elements takes O(N log K) time using an algorithm like this that keeps the input lists in a priority queue are repeatedly picks the smallest element from all of the head items: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/

Your magic register bank lets you do that K-way merge in O(N) time.  You can get the results you want by using that capability to implement merge sort, but instead of doing 2-way merges at each level, you do K-way merges at each level:

- Sort all length-K sublists in O(N) total time
- Merge every group of K lists into a length K^2 list in O(N) total time
- Same to create lists of length K^3, etc.

The sort will take O(N) per level * log_k(N) levels, for a total of O(N log_k(N)) = O(N log(N)/log(K)) time

Comment: What I want to know is how they got a priority queue that does insert and remove in O(1). That would allow an O(n) comparison sort.